# Solving $\sin(\frac{\pi}{12}+x)=\sin (2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

After getting to the above equation in a problem, I'm a bit stuck. Apparently, it's supposed to evaluate to $\frac{\pi}{12} + x=\pi -2x$, but I don't really see how.

Edit: I already had the solution $x=\frac{\pi}{12}$

Comment: $\sin a \equiv \sin (\pi - a)$

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I don't really see how that would help here. $\sin(\frac{\pi}{12} + x)= \sin(\pi-2x)$ doesn't seem much easier to solve.

Comment: You just have to remove the $\sin$ from both sides, not that it's formally allowed.

Comment: Are you supposed to find *all* solutions, or just *a* solution?

Comment: I'm supposed to find a solution that is not $x=\frac{\pi}{12}$

Comment: @Marcel, you should edit the question to say that.

Comment: @KennyLau In that case, why doesn't simply removing the $\sin$ from both sides (taking $\arcsin$ of both sides) work directly?

Comment: Start by taking the inverse sin of both sides.  That gives you a very simple algebra problem to find one solution.  However there may be additional solutions.  Where you will need to apply the identities such as the one @KennyLau has offered.

Comment: Of course - there are two possibilities due to the identity @KennyLau mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin{a}=\sin{b}$ means $a=b+2k\pi$ with $k\in\Bbb{Z}$ **or** $\pi-a=b+2k\pi$. So we have two sets of solutions:

$$x={\pi\over 12}+2k\pi$$

or

$$x={11\pi\over 36}+2k{\pi\over 3}$$

Comment: Ah, now I see - obvious really when you think about it. Is there an equivalent for cosine? Obviously, $\cos(a)\ne \cos(\pi-a)$

Comment: For cosine it is $a=b\pmod{2\pi}$ or $a=-b\pmod{2\pi}$

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many solutions.

We have 
$$
2x=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(\frac{\pi}{12}+x\right)\qquad (n\in\mathbf{Z})
$$

If $n$ is even,

\begin{align*}
2x&=n\pi+\left(\frac{\pi}{12}+x\right)\\
x&=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{12}
\end{align*}

If $n$ is odd,
\begin{align*}
2x&=n\pi-\left(\frac{\pi}{12}+x\right)\\
x&=\frac{n\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{36}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

HINT: write your equation in the form
$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{12}+x)-\sin(2x)=0$$ and use that
$$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\,\cos \left( x/2+y/2 \right) \sin \left( x/2-y/2 \right)$$